# Token expires when uploading bigger files in python

Tags: python-3.x

I have a function to upload a file through rest API which uses token for authorization which expires in 30 minutes. When I upload a big file I get timeout and the code breaks. The token `grant_type=password` and the response does not include refresh token. Can someone help me with it. Below is the function.

```
def post_Return_File(url, token, uploadFile):
    import requests
    from os.path import splitext
    
    #post urls ----change here
    head = {'Authorization':'Bearer ' + token}
    
    files_to_upload = []
    file_num = 0
    for files in uploadFile:
        file_num = file_num + 1
        fileName = 'file' + str(file_num)
        filepath = (fileName,(files, open(files,'rb'), (splitext(files)[-1]).strip('.')))
        files_to_upload.append(filepath)
    
    #sending the request for response
    post_res = requests.post(url, headers = head, files = files_to_upload)
    
    if (post_res.status_code == 200):
        post_response = post_res.status_code
        return post_response
    else:
        post_err = post_res.status_code 
        return post_err
```

Comment: what is a "big file" size and does it take more than 30 min for you to upload it?

Comment: bigger file size from 100MB and above

Comment: And what error code do you get? "Code breaks" does not explain it properly and posting logs etc would help.

Comment: File "C:\#\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 498, in send
    raise ConnectionError(err, request=request)

ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host', None, 10054, None))

Comment: I don't think that this is an issue with your code, but with the connection/authorization.  It looks like the tokens are set via a 3rd party, like Auth0, and there is a web flow timeout setting ... usually it defaults to 120m, so they must have this limited to 30m for a reason.  You will either need a faster connection or talk to the team setting up the tokens to have them adjust the timeout.